# Why can't I download games, apps, etc from any site except the Official Android Market?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, unknown-sources

Every time I try to download any of the games I love from any site except the Android Market, my phone tells me that the settings are set to not allow unknown apps to be run on my phone.

By the way I have an HTC Destiny. Don't have a book for it. If anyone could help me, I would appreciate it greatly. Again thank anyone who can help. I'm a total newbie to the android world, but think I will b a fan if i can  just figure a couple things out!! Lol.

Answer (score 27):

You can allow your device to install non-Market apps by going to "Settings" > "Applications" and checking "Unknown Sources". This should allow you to install non-Market apps although your settings menu may be slightly different.

Once you have it enabled [check out this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/5316/2422) if you need more info.

If you are on AT&T in the U.S. you should [check out this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/1070/2422).

Answer (score 8):

Depending on which phone network you got your phone from, you should be able to change that setting (I believe that AT&T in the US don't allow that setting to be changed).

Go into settings on your phone (on the home screen press <kbd>Menu</kbd> and then select **Settings**

From the Settings menu, select **Applications**

In that screen you should see a tickbox labelled **Unknown Sources** *Allow installation of non-Market applications* If you take the tick out of that box, then you should be able to install any apps that you want to.

Answer (score 4):

You can go in "Settings" -> "Applications" and make sure the "Unknown sources" option is checked. Then you should be able to install apps that are not from the Market.

Comment: Heh looks like we posted at the same time!

Comment: @GAThrawn You and I had a 6 second difference :)

Comment: Stack Exchange should implement a lock mechanism as it is done in some source management systems :)