# I need an app that transfers SMS to SD and can be moved to SD card itself

Tags: sms, external-sd, data-transfer

I just transferred phones from a Motorola Droid 2 to the Galaxy S III.  I usually use Handcent, but forgot to back up my SMS before the new phone was activated.  Now I have all my old SMS logs on the Droid, which can't back up because I have no data stream.

I've found multiple apps that can save SMS to the SD card and downloaded them to the S3, however I can't move any of those apps to the SD card to transfer the SD card to the Droid and install the SMS to SD backup app there.

I've tried using this [Guide](http://techgage.com/article/moving_your_non-movable_android_apps_to_an_sd_card) but even then, the apps won't move to the SD card. I don't want to root my new phone just to get an app transferred off it.

Can anyone give me suggestions for an app that meets that criteria or another solution?

Comment: PS: Moving to the SD card **only** works on the phone you did the move on (you *cannot* swap the SD card and hope that the app shows up on the *other* phone: It's for **security** reasons tied to the phone you installed it and did the move). And normally, this type of questions are considered a bad fit here as per the [FAQ](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq), however this one has a definite and final answer: LifeSaver2 (it's completely FOSS and thus won't go away). See my answer below.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out the "app on sd" part. For other readers: No longer having a data connection, one cannot install apps from the playstore. And if I'm not mistaken, the Droid² being CDMA, one cannot even temporarily switch the SIM card...

Comment: You're a life saver - literally.  Thank you SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the old version of LifeSaver2 available from the free & open source Android app repostitory http://f-droid.org

It's available [here](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=life&fdid=com.textuality.lifesaver2) or via the [FDroid market app](https://f-droid.org/FDroid.apk) itself.

To be able to install it you need to enable [*unknown sources*](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7708/why-cant-i-download-games-apps-etc-from-any-site-except-the-official-android).

If you have no data connection on your old phone: Put the LifeSaver2_1.0.apk on the SD card using your S3 or transfer it via Bluetooth and then side-load it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just move everything through your Gmail account, using [SMS Backup +](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync).
(I recommend using wifi, as it can take a while on a mobile data connection, if you have a lot of content.)