# How to install from an unknown source with my AT&T Galaxy S phone?

Tags: installation

I have an AT&T Galaxy S phone, but I can't find `install from an unknown source`. How can I install apps I receive?

Comment: May help a bit: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/how-to-install-from-unknown-sources-on-att

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install Android Central Sideload Wonder Machine to your computer and connect your device to the computer. This [link](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-sideload-wonder-machine/76171-android-central-sideload-wonder-machine-v-1-2-a.html) will surely help you out. Just follow every step carefully and you will get rid of that issue. Hope that helps.